# get the count of table rows

Tags: count, table

What is wrong in my code? It doesn't get the count but it is inserting into the database.

```
function r_rate_recipe()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $output = array('status' => 1);
    $post_id = absint($_POST['rid']);
    $rating = round($_POST['rating'], 1);
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $rating_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '" . $wpdb->prefix . "racipe_ratings'
            WHERE recipe_id='" . $post_id . "' AND user_ip='" . $user_ip . "'"
    );


    if ($rating_count > 0) {
        wp_send_json($output);
    }


    $wpdb->insert(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'racipe_ratings',
        array(
            'recipe_id' => $post_id,
            'rating' => $rating,
            'user_ip' => $user_ip
        ),
        array('%d', '%f', '%s')
    );
    $output['status'] = 2;
    wp_send_json($output);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that's you must using :

> $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options WHERE
>   option_id = 1", OBJECT );

And if you give us the message of error ?